# CSS two columns layout with Javascript document.write

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I am trying to finish my resume builder program for a class project. I have all requirements done except for the formatting and I am terrible with CSS. I have to use the document.write function for all of my output so please keep that in mind.

Javascript

```
document.write("<div id=\"theLeft\"><p>Career Objective: </div>");
document.write("<div id=\"theRight\""+co+"</p></div>");
```

That is just one of my rows and it outputs the first part but nothing shows up on the right for my variable. I've tried it with just regular paragraph tags and everything works fine just not correctly formatted.

CSS

```
<style>  
body {
font-size:12pt;
 font-family:verdana;
}

div#theLeft {
clear:both;
width:15%;
float:left;
}

div#theRight {
width:83%;
float:right;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}  
</style>
```

I have tried removing the padding and decreasing the width as well and still nothing has worked. I am sorry for such a basic question but I've looked at many other two-column layout answer threads and gotten nothing to work still.

Comment: prefer to create a sandbox or fiddle and provide the link in the question.

Comment: Out of curiosity... `document.write()` has been deprecated for like 20 years. Are they really still teaching it in schools?

Comment: yea unfortunately, for some reason she wanted us to use it for the final proj despite teaching us the innerHTML method which I like much much more.

Answer (score 1):

In your second `document.write()` you forgot to close the `<div>` element, as well left out a `<p>` tag. Escaping `"` can be annoying to do. You can create strings with either a single quotation mark `'` or double quotation marks `"`. Combining them allows you to use one of them as strings.

```
document.write('<div id="theLeft"><p>Career Objective: </div>');
document.write('<div id="theRight"><p>' + co + '</p></div>');
```

As for your CSS, steer clear of the `float` and `clear` properties. These properties are the old way of making layouts. I'd even suggest that you look for a more up-to-date class to take on web development.

Nowadays we have [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Flexbox) (1 dimensional layout) and [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) (2 dimensional layout) to create our layouts. These tools are specifically made to position elements in either a flexible flow or a (predetermined) grid. For this example I'll use CSS Grid.

CSS Grid Layout is a `display` type, like `block`, `inline` and `flex`, and has it's own properties to create a grid. In this case you want 2 columns.

First set the display property to grid:

```
body {
  display: grid;
}
```

Now your body is a **Grid Parent**, meaning that all the direct children in the body are **Grid Children** and can be positioned in the grid.
Create a layout with the following properties.

```
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}
```

`grid-template-rows` specifies how many rows should be in this grid. In this case we've set it to 1 row width an `auto` height. It is comparable to setting the `height: auto;` property, but for a single row.
`grid-template-columns` sets the amount of columns in the grid. In it we specify 2 columns and use the new `fr` value. `fr` stands for *fraction* and in this case it means: *"Between the two columns divide the space. Give the first column 2 out of the 3 fractions and the second column 1 out of the 3 fractions."*. This ends up to a `66.6%` and `33.3%` division of space.

You can also give your rows and columns a name with the `grid-template-areas` property. It detects the rows and columns we already defined and allows us to give them names with a string.

```
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "left right";
}
```

This says that the first column in the first row is called `left` and the second column in the first row is called `right`. And you can assign your child elements to it like this with the `grid-area` property.

```
div#theLeft {
  grid-area: left;
}

div#theRight {
  grid-area: right;
}
```

Below here is a working example of your code with CSS Grid

```js
var co = 'To be the best!';

document.write('<div id="theLeft"><p>Career Objective: </div>');
document.write('<div id="theRight"><p>' + co + '</p></div>');
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "left right";
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: verdana;
}

div {
  padding: 20px;
}

div#theLeft {
  grid-area: left;
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
}

div#theRight {
  grid-area: right;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Comment: I tried your changes but it seems to just put  what is supposed to be on the right below as if i created a new line.

Comment: I've added a small tutorial regarding more modern layout techniques. I recommend, if you want to learn CSS the right way, that you drop `float` and `clear` and only work with either Flexbox or CSS Grid Layout to build your layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out what your strings look like by either [setting a breakpoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Set_a_breakpoint) in your browser's debugger or with the [`console` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console). That way the typos become obvious:

```js
var co = "Hellow, World!";
console.log("<div id=\"theLeft\"><p>Career Objective: </div>");
console.log("<div id=\"theRight\""+co+"</p></div>");
```

Also, if as I suspect `co` contains raw unescaped plain text your code is unsafe and can easily break. Please compare:

```js
var co = "When X<Y then Hellow, World!";
console.log("<div id=\"theRight\">"+co+"</p></div>");
console.log("<div id=\"theRight\">"+encodeHTML(co)+"</p></div>");

document.write("<div id=\"theRight\">"+co+"</p></div>");
document.write("<div id=\"theRight\">"+encodeHTML(co)+"</p></div>");

function encodeHTML(plainText){
    return String(plainText)
        .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
        .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
        .replace(/'/g, "&#039;")
        .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
        .replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
}
```

Last but not least, the 21st century way to do it would be using the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), e.g.:

```js
var co = "When X<Y then Hellow, World!";
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "theRight";
div.innerText = co;
document.querySelector("section").appendChild(div);
```

```html
<section></section>
```